# jboss 5 changing default port

Tags: jboss

I am trying to change the default port on my jboss server to port 80.

i have had a look around the web and i have had suggestions of editing this file jboss5\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml  which is fine. changing this file alone still does not fix the issue.

There have also been suggestion to also change this file: 
jboss5\server\default\conf\bootstrap\bindings.xml  Only problem is that i cant find this binding.xml

Is the binding.xml file a standard in JBoss 5?  Or has it been renamed or changes location in JBoss 5.

Does anyone have any clear steps on changing the the default port from 8080 to 80.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably after jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/standard/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml

See

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"

               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Don't forget that ports below 1024 are generally reserved, and can only be claimed by privileged users (root). Depending on your situation, it may be useful to put an apache reverse proxy in between.

Comment: Hi Vincent

thanks for your response,  I tried changing the port 8080 to 80 but still haven't had any luck.

Comment: captain obvious question: you did restart jboss after modifying the xml file right? if so, are you passing any arguments to the startup script?

Answer (score 1):

Change the bindings-jboss-beans in jboss/server//conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF

jboss.web:service=WebServer
               **8080**

Change the port 8080 to 80 or any other that you wish.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am running custom server (openmobster) under jboss 5.1 GA on Ubuntu 10.04 and i solved it as following

- edit PATH_JBOSS_HOME/server/openmobster/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml and change port in following line to your desired port (e.g. change 8080 to 8090)

`<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />`

- edit PATH_JOBSS_HOME/server/openmobster/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml and change value 8080 to your desired port (8090)

`<property name="serviceName">jboss.web:service=WebServer</property>
               <property name="port">8080</property>`

and restart the server. It started successfully on `http://HOST:8090/`